# Understanding HingeConstraint in jBullet

Tags: java, bullet-physics, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm using the java port of BulletPhysics engine [jBullet](http://jbullet.advel.cz).
I'd like to make a joints between 2 triangles so that one edge of the first and one edge of the seconds act like a hinge.

But I don't understand how to use the HingeConstraint class because it [lacks documentation](http://jbullet.advel.cz/javadoc/com/bulletphysics/dynamics/constraintsolver/HingeConstraint.html#HingeConstraint(com.bulletphysics.dynamics.RigidBody,%20com.bulletphysics.dynamics.RigidBody,%20javax.vecmath.Vector3f,%20javax.vecmath.Vector3f,%20javax.vecmath.Vector3f,%20javax.vecmath.Vector3f)). What `pivotInA` and `pivotInB` are? They are the pivot points of the hinge in respect to the object centre? And `axisInA`? How does it differs from `axisInA`?

For two triangles do I have to make 2 Hinge constrains in 2 vertex or 1 in the middle point of the 2 edges of the hinge?

Where can I find a simple working example of this?

Answer (score 1):

When I ported from OpenDE to Bullet, I was puzzled about this as well. [I asked on the forum](https://pybullet.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=10151&p=34130#p34130), and the author answered.

*In Bullet you can initialize a Hinge constraint that is in a unsatisfied condition.*

Only when the axes from both point of views (body A and body B) coincide, the constraint is satisfied.

He makes a good point. Could be useful to serialize a simulation exactly as-is, with constraint error and all.

Answer (score 0):

Hinge constraint between two rigid bodies each with a pivot point that descibes the axis location in local space. Axis defines the orientation of the hinge axis.  I have found documentation on this [here](http://jbullet.advel.cz/javadoc/com/bulletphysics/dynamics/constraintsolver/HingeConstraint.html).

Comment: there are no description in the documentation you posted (that is the same I have linked)